# C# Calculate items in List<int> values vertically

Tags: c#

I have a list of int values some thing like below (upper bound and lower bounds are dynamic)

```
1, 2, 3
4, 6, 0
5, 7, 1
```

I want to calculate the column values in vertical wise like

```
1 + 4 + 5 = 10
2 + 6 + 7 = 15
3 + 0 + 1 = 4
```

Expected Result = `10,15,4`

Any help would be appreciated

Thanks

Deepu

Comment: How do you have the input data? A `List<int>` is 1-dimension; so is it {1,2,3,4,6,0,5,7,1}? or what?

Comment: How are you storing the numbers? Are they all in a single nine-element list?

Comment: Very bad question, I believe even for such simple question you need SO experts to help you, will you ever be able to write any code by yourself, I hate to see programmers not knowing basics of arrays and logic !!

Comment: Marc, I have a list of int array and I want to calculate the sum of every column in vertically

List<int[]> qtyList = new List<int[]>();

qtyList.Add(new int[] {2,3,5});

qtyList.Add(new int[] {1,0,4});

qtyList.Add(new int[] {5,0,3});

Hope you understand...

Thanks
Deepu

Comment: @Deepu - you shoule update your question and title to reflect that you have a List<int[]> rather than List<int>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the input data using array literals, but the subsequent code works exactly the same on arrays or lists.

```
var grid = new []
           {
               new [] {1, 2, 3},
               new [] {4, 6, 0},
               new [] {5, 7, 1},
           };
```

Now produce a sequence with one item for each column (take the number of elements in the shortest row), in which the value of the item is the sum of the row[column] value:

```
var totals = Enumerable.Range(0, grid.Min(row => row.Count()))
                       .Select(column => grid.Sum(row => row[column]));
```

Print that:

```
foreach (var total in totals)
    Console.WriteLine(total);
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use a 2D array you can just sum the first, second,... column of each row.

If you use a 1D array you can simply use a modulo:

```
int[] results = new results[colCount];
for(int i=0, i<list.Count; list++)
{
  results[i%colCount] += list[i];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have to use a "List"-object? Elseway, I would use a twodimensional array.

Otherwise, you simply could try, how to reach rows and columns separatly, so you can add the numbers within a simply for-loop. It depends on the methods of the List-object.

Answer (score 0):

Quite inflexible based on the question, but how about:

```
int ans = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i+=3)
{
    ans+= list[i];
}
```

You could either run the same thing 3 times with a different initial iterator value, or put the whole thing in another loop with *startValue* as an interator that runs 3 times.

Having said this, you may want to a) look at a different way of storing your data if, indeed they are in a single list b) look at more flexible ways to to this or wrap in to a function which allows you to take in to account different column numbers etc...

Cheers,
Adam